# Разделение доступа в pypiserver

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Настраиваю приватный PyPi server и никак не могу понять, как там делается разделение доступа.

Если поискать в инете, то можно найти вот такое

```
./pypi-server -p 8080 -P htpasswd.txt -a update,download,list
```

где -a это операции для которых пароль.

Но глупо закрывать паролем список и скачивание и тем же паролем закрывать обновление. Должно же быть разделение, чтобы и не публично вовсе и пароль не один.

В доке написано загадочное

> You need to restart the server with the -P option only once (but
> user/password pairs can later be added or updated on the fly):

Но не раскрывается что это значит. Как, куда, на каком лету можно добавить еще паролей и как это разделять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что фраза

> but user/password pairs can later be added or updated on the fly

все лишь о том, что в файл `htpasswd.txt` можно добавить строчек с пользователями и делать это можно не перегружая сервер, так как pypiserver следит за меткой времени этого файла.

А вот разделить вид доступа нельзя. По меньшей мере в варианте с `htpasswd`.

Нет никакой связи `метод + пользователь`.
При запросе сервер проверяет не упомянута ли вызываемая функция `api` в списке из параметра `-a`. И, если да, то просто ищет пару логин пароль в `htpasswd.txt`.

А значит либо править функцию авторизации, либо поставить впереди что-то вроде nginx и сделать защиту индекса пакетов в нем.